# OpenSSL in GitLab, what verification for self-signed certificate?

Tags: ssl, gitlab

On [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian), using [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/index.html), I ran into issues with my self-signed certificate.

Reading through the code after a lot of searching on the Internet (I guess, it's the last resort, [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open_source_software) is helpful), I found the following lines in `gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb` which left me... perplexed.

```
if config.http_settings['self_signed_cert']
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end
```

Most Stack Overflow responses about the diverse issues I've had until now have led me to believe that VERIFY_NONE, as you'd expect, doesn't verify anything. VERIFY_PEER seems, based on my reading, to be the correct setting for self-signed.

As I read it, it feels like taking steps to secure my connection using a certificate, and then just deciding to not use it? Is it a bug, or am I misreading the source?

Comment: Mislav, from Github, seems to not like "verify_none". Lets me even more perplexed. http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2013/07/ruby-openssl/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[gitlab-shell](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell) (on the GitLab server) has to communicate to the GitLab instance through an [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) or [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) API.
If it is a self-signed certificate, it doesn't want any error/warning when trying to access those GitLab URLs, hence the `SSL::VERIFY_NONE`.

But, that same certificate is also used by clients (outside of the GitLab server), using those same GitLab HTTPS URLs from their browser.
For them, the self-signed certificate is useful, provided they install it in their browser keystore.
For those transactions (clients to GitLab), the certificate will be "verified".

---

The [OP Kheldar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/805252/kheldar)  [point's out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274561/openssl-in-gitlab-what-verification-for-self-signed-certificate/22274847#comment33837079_22274847) in [Mislav's post](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2013/07/ruby-openssl/):

> OpenSSL expects to find each certificate in a file named by the certificate subject’s hashed name, plus a number extension that starts with 0.
>
> That means you can’t just drop `My_Awesome_CA_Cert.pem` in the directory and expect it to be picked up automatically.
> However, OpenSSL ships with a utility called `c_rehash` which you can invoke on a directory to have all certificates indexed with appropriately named symlinks.

(See for instance [OpenSSL Verify location](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html#EXAMPLES))

```
cd /some/where/certs
c_rehash .
```

Comment: You're partially correct, I believe. I added Mislav's post, which has an important information I had missed (necessity to run c_rehash the folder containing my self-signed certificate). This prevents the need from using VERIFY_NONE. My understanding is  that config.http_settings['self_signed_cert'] in Gitlab's code is a ugly hack that should be marked as such, but is used for the reasons you explained.

Comment: @Kheldar I agree, and I have added a link to Mislav's post and `c_rehash` example OpenSSL man page in the (now edited) answer.